# What is the most compatible/correct way of forcing non-www and forcing https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for some help finding the most compatible and more importantly the correct way of forcing of non-`www.` and forcing https

## Forcing non-`www.` according to Apache (these rule is for adding www. so would need a tiny adjustment)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

For sites running on a port other than 80:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^$"
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "!^80$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)         "http://www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

And for a site running on port 80

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^www\.example\.com" [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://www.example.com/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

If you wanted to do this generically for all domain names - that is, if you want to redirect example.com to www.example.com for all possible values of example.com, you could use the following recipe:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^www\." [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"      "http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L,R,NE]
```

## Forcing HTTPS according to Apache

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Just searching Stackoverflow there are hundreds of examples all different, all with different styles, all with various regex rules, all with various options, some merged, some not merged...

For example some various ones below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.examplewebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://examplewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^examplewebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://examplewebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www*\.(.*examplewebsite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www*\.(.*examplewebsite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Currently I am using:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force HTTPS & NON-WWW
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^examplewebsite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://examplewebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Found via: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/issues/48

But I would like to know:

- If it can be improved to be more compatible.
- If it can be made dynamic (Is there a way to remove the need for defining the website name?)
- If it needs any extra tags like QSA, NE or if R should be 301 or blank?

I also need a second rule for JUST removing www for a .htaccess file in a subfolder.

**Currently I am using:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force Removal of WWW
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I assume this one is slightly better:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Force Removal of WWW
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It's pretty dynamic but like above, can any improvements be made? Is there a better rule out there, is the rule from apache better?